# Returning different number formats with Index Match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an index match set up to take information from another table using a dropdown. All works fine expect for some of the information in the table is a number and some is a percentage. Which means the percentage is retuned as 0.8 for example rather than 80%

I'm using =INDEX(E42:E50,MATCH(A3,A42:A50,0)) where A3 is the dropdown and was wondering if there was an EXACT I could use in there to get the right format?

I might be way off so any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Why don't you format the cell where your formula sits in into percentage? The formula works fine because it's the numeric equivalent of 80%. In fact, the actual value in the source is not 80% but it's numerical equivalent. It's just formatted to show 80%.

Comment: In addition to @JvdV, use paste special -> formula only. It will preserve formatting. Avoid simple copy/paste and also do not "slide" the first cell to complete the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "EXACT" available here, conceptually, as to Excel, the value is precisely (EXACT-ly) the same regardless of formatting. Formatting is just formatting:  it makes NO change to the underlying values.

However, Excel CAN tell what the numerical format of a cell is so long as a standard, provided, format is used. So you could use the `CELL("format",cell address)` function to find that out.

A couple difficulties though:

1. Your formula is returning a value, not an actual cell address. Fortunately, if you can find the value with INDEX/MATCH, you can find a cell address. It just adds a whole extra layer to your formula.
2. Knowing the format of your target is only half the battle. You now have to format your output cell the same to accomplish your goal. But Excel does NOT offer a way for a formula to format its output. Not past simplicities like `TEXT()` which won't even (directly) allow color formatting, just the string's text output.

The first is straightforward to accomplish using `ADDRESS()` and the row/column information developed for the INDEX/MATCH. One would wrap the `ADDRESS()` function with `INDIRECT()`.

For the second, you can use that information in a Conditional Formatting rule's test formula. For example, if the `CELL()` function, used on the cell returned by the above paragraph, returns "P2", then the format applied could be set to be a two decimal place percentage (so, "80.00%). If multiple percent formats are possible (the value might show as 80%, 80.0%, 80.00%, that kind of thing), and you have to allow for all of them, you'll need several CF rules with each having "Stop IF True" checked. Use regular formatting to format for the non-percent targets. Or vice-versa.

So format for one or the other with regular formatting. Use your formula to find the target value. Use the same information, plus `INDIRECT()`, in the CF test rule formula to create an address and `CELL()` to find its number format. That's half the test rule and say it equals the string for the percent (or regular) format you are testing for. So like this:

```
= CELL( "format", INDIRECT( ADDRESS ))) = "P0"
```

(with that first half of it looking a lot more complicated!).

Set the formatting for a successful test to match that (80% in this example).

Regular formatting then takes care of non-matches. CF takes care of matches. And your current formula finds the value to format.